# Shut down of macOS takes forever

Tags: macos, big-sur, shutdown

I have a MacBook Air 2014 with macOS Big Sur. Shutting it down takes over a minute! Only when being logged in though. If I shut it down before logging in right in the login screen it just takes a few seconds to turn off.

Is this normal? If not, is there something I can do to speed up the shut down process? I've tried to switch off all iCloud synchronizations, to no effect. Shut down still takes forever.

**Update:** The dock and the menu bar go away immediatly, but the backgound picture is visible till the end. The spinner appears after about 10 seconds.

When I log out first: The log out is reasonaly fast, but when I then click on shut down there is a blank screen with a spinner for about a minute before it turns off.

Comment: How long does shutdown take if you logout first?

Comment: And to add onto that, which steps take a while. Do you still see the dock and menu bar while it's doing this or do you just see a blank screen with a spinner.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: It is one or two apps being slow to shutdown - all you can do is try the shutdown with different apps open

Comment: All apps are closed. Not just minimized, but actually cmd-Q closed.

Comment: Have you tried a [Safe Boot](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @DavidSupportsMonica to try safe mode brought me on the right track. The problem did not occur with safe mode. As suggested [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262), I created a new user account with which the problem also did not occur.

Fortunately I remembered having registered *jack* to be started at boot, which turned out to be the culprit: *jack* simply won't stop. I guess at some point the shut down process reaches a timeout and just turns the machine off.

I've created an [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/issues/387) with brew-services.

Comment: So quitting or killing jack before logout solves the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to properly quit jack. But starting jack in the second account I created, which initially did not show the behavior, did reproduce the problem.