# How to disable a broken brew service?

Tags: homebrew, launchd

For the *moc* music player I have installed *jack* and started it as a service with:

```
brew services start jack
```

This causes *jack* to be startet at login. It works for *moc*, but unfortunately it seems that *jack* cannot be stopped causing my Mac to [take a very long time to shut down](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/429672/255436); presumably waiting for *jack* to stop until some timeout is reached.

The obvious command to stop *jack* would be:

```
brew services stop jack
```

Unfortunately, this command does not terminate and *jack* will be started again upon the next login.

How can I prevent *jack* from being started at login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent jack to start at login or boot remove the file `homebrew.mxcl.jack.plist` from `~/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchDaemons`(depending on if you install it with sudo or not).

According to `man brew`:

> brew services [subcommand]
> Manage background services with macOS launchctl(1) daemon manager.
>
> If sudo is passed, operate on /Library/LaunchDaemons (started at boot). Otherwise, operate on ~/Library/LaunchAgents (started at login).